# Is it possible to use VNC Server Enterprise for Monitor swapping, and establish external connections?

Tags: vnc, vncserver, realvnc

I am considering purchasing the full license of VNC server enterprise:

Q1 - I am currently using VNC Free outside my home firewall via first setting up an encrypted SSH tunnel over port 443 to my home Mac, then running VNC on top of this layer (for security) and via port 443 (to eliminate firewall port configuration issues). Is it possible with
VNC server enterprise (running on Mac at home) to be able to establish an external (over internet) connection to my home Mac which is:

(a) encrypted/secure VNC connection, which
(b) uses port 443, and
(c) for which the client can be configured with proxy settings with username/password?

Q2 - Is it possible at the client end to swap the monitor mode from say (a) Monitor 0 only, to (b) Monitor 0+1, then back again?